# How to get nested jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to a Link. But I does not seem to work. I tried all the possible ways and looked already for a long time on google. can I access this tag anyhow?

But I corrected my question, sorry. I want to use the first child of the listing so e.g.  product--box box--minimal - there are multiple ones.

```
$('div.listing > div.box--content.is--rounded > div.product--info > a').addClass('test');

<div class="product--box box--minimal" data-page-index="" data-ordernumber="XXXX">
    <div class="box--content is--rounded">
        <div class="product--info">
            <a href="XXXXX" title="XXXXX" class="product--image">
                <span class="image--element">
                    <span class="image--media">
                        <img srcset="XXXXX.jpg, XXXXXX2x.jpg 2x" alt="KXXXX" title="XXX">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div class="product--rating-container"></div>
            <span>XXX</span>
            <a href="hXXXXXXX" class="product--title" title="XXXX">
                XXXXXX
            </a>
            <div class="product--price-info">
                <div class="product--price-outer">
                    <div class="product--price">
                        <span class="price--default is--nowrap">XXXXXX</span>
                        <div style="display:none;">ab</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: div.box--content.is--rounded is not a direct descendant of div.listing. Replace the > with spaces

Comment: @LDJ — Yes it is. The problem is that it isn't a child of it.

Comment: Sorry if I didnt mention that. But there are more then one box--content is--rounded and I want to choose the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of your use of the child selector (`>`), and that `.box--content.is--rounded` is not the direct child of `div.listing`. Try this instead:

```
$('div.listing > div.product--box.box--minimal > div.box--content.is--rounded > div.product--info > a').addClass('test');
```

Alternatively, as both `a` elements are within the same container and will be caught by that selector, you can simplify it to just this:

```
$('div.listing a').addClass('test');
```

> I want to use the first child of the listing so e.g. `product--box box--minimal` - there are multiple ones.

In this case you can use the `:first` selector:

```
$('div.listing > div.product--box.box--minimal:first > div.box--content.is--rounded > div.product--info > a').addClass('test');

// or, more simply:

$('div.listing div.product--box.box--minimal:first a').addClass('test');
```

Comment: "direct child selector" — It's called a "child combinator" (and used to be called the "child selector"). I don't know where you got the word "direct" from, selectors don't distinguish between "direct" and anything ("adopted" maybe?) else.

Comment: But I corrected my question, sorry. I want to use the first child of the listing so e.g.  product--box box--minimal - there are multiple ones.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
div.listing > div.box--content.is--rounded
```

This tries to match a div element that is a member of the class *box--content.is--rounded* which is a **child** of a div that is a member of a class *listing*.

… but that doesn't exist.

In your HTML `div.box--content.is--rounded` is the **grand**child of `div.listing`.

You should probably be using descendant combinators () in at least some of the places you are currently using child combinators (`>`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below based on your requirement

//**The children() method returns all direct children of the selected element.**

```
$("div.listing").children("a").addClass('test')
```

**//The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element, all the way down to the last descendant.**

```
$("div.listing").find("a").addClass('test')
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I misinterpreted your question, the appropriate selector would be:

```
$('body > div > div > div > div > a.product--image')
```

Comment: 1) this has nothing to do with any event, let alone `click` 2) `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago, and you really shouldn't be using it any more.

Comment: Even then, `on()` is not at all relevant here.

Comment: This question is not related to what you have answered.